# Google Chrome Extension error: Requires Dev Channel or Newer

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a "url-shortcut" extension for chrome. While adding it to the browser I received the following error:

> There were warnings when trying to install this extension:
>          *  'app.linked_icons' requires Google Chrome dev channel or newer, but this is the stable channel.

This is my **manifest.json**:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Google Fit",
    "short_name": "Fit",
    "description": "Google Fit",
    "key": "Eg+2zP54mEfjusi2n1/gjO7gvXchXiDBSaWgxn2Sssg=",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {
        "128": "128.png"
    },
    "app": {
        "urls": [
            "https://fit.google.com/"
        ],
        "launch": {
            "web_url": "https://fit.google.com/"
        },
        "linked_icons": [  ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "notifications"
    ]
}
```

Comment: And what do you want exactly? The error message says clearly the stable channel is unsupported.

Answer (score 4):

linked_icons in app should be with channel like below.

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Google Fit",
    "short_name": "Fit",
    "description": "Google Fit",
    "key": "Eg+2zP54mEfjusi2n1/gjO7gvXchXiDBSaWgxn2Sssg=",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {
       "128": "128.png"
    },
    "app": {
        "urls": [
            "https://fit.google.com/"
        ],
        "launch": {
            "web_url": "https://fit.google.com/"
        },
        "linked_icons": [
           "channel" : "dev"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "notifications"
    ]
}
```

Comment: `["key": "value"]` is invalid syntax and Chrome [does not read any `channel` keys](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/browser/extensions/convert_web_app.cc&q=linked_icons&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=118).

Answer (score 0):

most of the users are on the Stable channel, because this is the default download available

If you want to use Dev or Canary builds. More information on using a different release channel can be found on chromium.org at [Chrome Release Channels](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel).